# Timeout::Error issue on Jenkins while test cases run locally

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, capybara

This is a weird situation I am facing when cucumber test cases pass alright locally but faces timeout error in Jenkins server after running few successful scenarios.The rest of the scenarios are skipped automatically.I am using xvfb on my Jenkins but no Jruby.Any help??